# vba insert dropdown list into cell in excel from outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to insert a drop down/validation list into my next available row in column 25.

I am getting a compile error on the following line:  `Formula1:=Join(MyList, ",")`

```
    Const Delete As Integer = 3
    Const Add As Integer = 4
    Const xlValidateList As Integer = 5
    Const AlertStyle As Integer = 6
    Const xlValidAlertStop As Integer = 7
    Const Operator As Integer = 8
    Const xlBetween As Integer = 9
    Const Formula1 As Integer = 10
    Const Join As Integer = 11

 intRow4 As Integer, _
intRow4 = excWks4.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

         Dim MyList(3) As String
                               MyList(0) = "Yes"
                               MyList(1) = "No"
                               MyList(2) = "Declined"
                               With excWks4.Cells(intRow4, 25).Validation
                               .Delete
                               .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                               Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyList, ",")
                               End With
```

I imagine its because outlook doesn't support, can someone please show me how I can get this to work? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Delete/comment-out all of your `Const` assignments. Using the xl enumerations directly is fine but defining variables with the same names as the Validation parameters is probably not a good idea.